# My laptop doesn't boot when I add a new RAM

Tags: boot, laptop, memory, motherboard, bios

Here's the thing :

I recently cleaned my laptop completely. And during my cleaning, I disassembled my CPU and then put it back (I wanted to see how it worked). Then I put everything back in (motherboard, keyboard, HDD, RAM, etc) and then my laptop didnt boot.

It took me time to understand but apparently my computer doens't detect my second RAM slot anymore (I have 2 slots). How do I know that ? Well I tested many combinations with my two 4Gb RAMs and make each of them work when they are alone on the 1st slot, but not on the second AND they don't work at the same time.

So it's not the RAMs that have a problem. I read on the internet and some people advise to flash the BIOS but I don't even know if it's possible. I restored the default parameters in the BIOS though and it didn't change anything. I also did the 1 min push on the power button cable unplugged and it didn't work. I read that I should do a CMOS but on laptops I don't know how you can do that, there's no CMOS jumper on my motherboard.

I don't know what to do now, can someone help me please ?

My motherboard is an ASUS X53S.

Ask me if you need other informations.

I PROBABLY have changed something in the CPU or so, but I don't know how and what. But I repeat that before that, my second slot was working.

Oh, by the way, I didn't try the first slot with a 4+GB, so I don't actually know if it's the slot itself that doens't work OR the system (BIOS ?) that doens't want to boot/load with more than 4GB, which I guess is also a possibility.

Help please. And thanks.

Comment: [This is a CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit). Sounds like physically damaged RAM slot to me.

Comment: Yes I know what is a CPU thanks, that's by the way exatly the same image (on Wikipedia) as the thing I dissembled when I was cleaning my computer. 

Yes the slot could indeed be damaged, the other possibility being that the BIOS doens't want to detect more than 4 GB anymore. Do you know if the second case is possible please ?

How do I repair the slot if it's damaged and why did my cleaning (where I barely touched the slot, just to remove the RAMs) break it ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if this could help : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEx9mq66blA ?

I have an ASUS, but I noticed a similar battery on the motherboard when I was cleaning it.

Comment: Removing the CMOS battery to rest the BIOS might work. I guess it's worth a shot to try. The RAM slot could have been damaged by static electricity, or simply damaged when removing/inserting the RAM stick again. It's kind of hard to tell. For future advice a good cleaning can be done by removing the bottom case and using compressed air to blow it out. Laptops have too much going on and are annoying to take apart, as you may have found out :)

Comment: Did you insert the CPU correctly? also did you put thermal paste on it? If that's not the problem, I think it's time to go to the repair shop, they have special equipment to diagnose and repair printed circuit boards. When it gets to that, it's no longer something you can do at home.

Comment: [I have a feeling if your laptop could talk...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjeptaI2T8E)

Comment: @DrZoo : yes i agree, Laptops aren't easy to repair, the access to to components is a difficult task and their are quite fragile. I removed the CMOS battery but it didn't change anything. I know it did something because when I lauched my windows, the date had changed to the day I bought it (5 years ago). But it didn't clear the RAM slots. I know the 2 RAMs both work in the 1st slot, so it appears that the second slot is indeed damaged, though I don't remember having done anything wrong (but these things are so fragile ...) Thanks for the advice on compressed air, I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @Florian : I'd prefer to fix it myself, it'll cost me more than 100 euros if i go the repair shop. Well I don't remember exactly if I put the CPU back in correctly but since the computer works, I guess it's the case, or it could work fine but still bug a slot (I don't know exactly how components interact, but I don't think that would be possible) ? I didn't put thermal paste for the moment, I just bought some on amazon, it'll come soon, but the heat isn't the problem I think, everything works fine but when I put RAM in the second slot, the computer doesn't boot (black screen, LEDs light on)

Comment: Ah dang, sorry you're still having issues with it. As far as the damage, if it was caused by ESD, it's likely that you had no idea you damaged it and were completely unaware of anything happening. Unless of course your finger made a good shock noise :) The part could have also been on the verge of dying and this could just be a fluke in timing. If you have anymore questions, just comment.

Comment: @DrZoo : thanks for your help, yes that might be it, indeed, that would explain why I seems to have happened without reason. No I didn't feel anything in my finger when I changed the RAMs :/

How can I change/repair that slot ?

Comment: The easy way to "repair" the slot is to get a new motherboard and replace it. The more complex and skilled way is to get a schematic, multi meter, and some fancy soldering tools. Then you test readings along the motherboard and see what part is bad and replace it. However, the advanced method is not something just anyone can do. I'd stick with replacing the motherboard.

Comment: @DrZoo changing the motherboard is going to cost me a lot I think and I think it's not easy to find :/

the method two seems hard too :/ I'll take a look into that, but I don't think I will do it.

If nothing works, I think I will use a 8 GB in the 1st slot (instead of 2 x 4GB), do you think it'll change something in performances ? (I heard about dual channeling, things like that)

Comment: Yes it can have a performance impact. What do you mostly do on your laptop?

Comment: I just redisambled my laptop and resinstalled the CPU properly and for some obscure reason my second slot works now. Maybe there was a little connection problem somewhere in the circuit. At least it works ! I'm relieved :) @DrZoo : mostly development (android studio, code blocks, web development) and also movies sometimes :)